# How can I validate a math expression syntax without calculate it

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I am trying to validate a mathematical expression like **(x + 5) * 3/y** in Python 3.
I was thinking to replace x and y with random values but in the example above if the rand value for y is 0 this will fail.

I searched how to validate a expression without evaluating the result:

```py
validate_expression("(x + 5) * 3/y hello world") # raise an exception
validate_expression("(x + 5) * 3/y") # do nothing
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide the
[shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
also make sure to provide some input and the corresponding desired output.

Comment: what's the problem? the question is perfectly clear.

Comment: You can generate random number >0 for y.

Comment: @georg: perfectly clear ? Please explain it.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "evaluate math expression without calculating it" since to evaluate an expression is exactly to calculate it.

Comment: this may be interesting for you: https://www.sympy.org/

Comment: @YvesDaoust: from my understanding, the OP is trying to "validate" a formula, that is, to check is it's syntactically valid. Of course, they should have used "validate" in the title too, to avoid confusion.

Comment: What is your criteria for a valid mathematical expression? What is your criteria for an *in*valid mathematical expression?

Comment: @georg: syntactic validity is immediately checked by the interpreter, so it is no big deal to supply values "by hand", is it ? Unless OP means an expression supplied at run-time.

Comment: I don't see exactly what is unclear in the question. Maybe a messy snippet is missing.

Comment: @georg That is a possible interpretation, but since OP used "validate" once and "evaluate" once, it is hard to know which one of the two was the intended meaning. Even if they did mean "validate", it isn't clear if *syntactical* validation is the issue so much as some sort of semantic validation against some unstated criteria.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi what I mean a valid mathematical expression is something that is syntaxical is correct.

Comment: @miorey So you are not looking for *mathematical* expressions but *Python* expressions? Do you care about the distinction between statements and expressions? For example, which of these would you consider valid/invalid: ``return x + 5``, ``import x``, ``a = 5``, ``Σ a``, ``Σ + a``, ``subprocess.call(["rm", "-rf", "/"])``, ``∫x dx``, ``f(x) = x + 5``, ``(x + 5) * 3/y # hello world``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I was searching for a python way to validate a python expression of a mathematical function. what georg gives above. The question wasn't maybe clear enough for the rules, but enough for the right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your expressions follow the Python rules, you can use [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to validate them:

```
import ast

expr = '(x + 5) * 3 ?'
try:
    ast.parse(expr)
    print('valid')
except SyntaxError:
    print('invalid')
```

As correctly pointed out in the comments, since this validates any python code, not only math expressions, you'll need to walk the parsed AST to make sure it doesn't contain things you don't want, like built-in functions.

Comment: while i like the idea also something like `f() + g(5); print(x)` will be valid...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: sure, the second step would be walk the `.parse` result and make sure it contains only the right stuff

Comment: ah, ok. good point! +1  i still think https://www.sympy.org/ might be less trouble for this usecase.